# emacs shell: remove all non-printable characters

Tags: shell-mode

When I call `gcalcli` from the bash shell, I get the output described in the documentation. But when I run `M-x shell` on emacs (24.3) and call `gcalcli` from there, I get a lot of `^[` characters. Compare screenshots from the shell and from emacs.

[image]
[image]

My `init.el` already contains the following lines, which are supposed to help with this.

```
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
          'comint-output-ctrl-m)
```

I don't really have a problem with calling `gcalcli` from the shell whenever I need it. I just want to understand why emacs uses non-printing characters here and how to suppress them if I want to.

Comment: Try doing `M-x` ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on `RET` in the shell buffer

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference.